# Room Database, Android Studio, Query problem with finding a name the ends with given string

Tags: android-sqlite, android-room

I am working with Android Studio room database. I have successfully used these queries to get names satisfying the query criteria.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM malenamesdb WHERE name LIKE '%' || :search || '%' AND selected ")
fun findByName(search: String?): List<MaleNamesDB>


@Query("SELECT * FROM malenamesdb WHERE name LIKE :search || '%' AND selected ")
fun maleNameBeginsWith(search: String?): List<MaleNamesDB>
```

But when I tried to create a query that is supposed to find all name that ends with a given string like so.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM malenamesdb where name LIKE '%' || :search")
fun maleNameEndsWith(search: String?): List<MaleNamesDB>
```

The result of maleNameEndsWith() function is an empty list, it dosent find anything. No matter what search string is prowidet.

It does not work, why is this not working and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add some information on what is the result of the query that does not work.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your query. Maybe try adding more information about what is the content of the database or what is the result in the queries that are working.